# Input/output error when write on internal hard drive. Sometimes works without errors. Read from that drive always works

Tags: mount, hard-drive, nautilus

1. INTRO:
   Dual boot windows and Ubuntu 18.04 with 1TB exFAT hard drive (/dev/sda2 mounted at /media/username/harddiskname) used only for data and which could be accessed from both operating systems. Everything works fine for months, but few days ago strange behavior started.
2. PROBLEM:

a)When saving filename.txt on that drive (from Gedit for example), I got error on red background on top of file opened id Gedit: 
"Could not save the file "/media/username/harddiskname/filename.txt": Unexpected error: Error opening file “/media/username/harddiskname/filename.txt”: Input/output error" (drive is properly mounted). But actually, when I open disk in file manager, filename.txt is created with 0kb.

b) In terminal, I am not able to create folder on that drive ("mkdir: cannot create directory "testdir": Input/output error". But actually, when I open file manager, that folder is created.

c) In file manager (Nautilus, Doplhin, Krusader) I am not able to create directory (popup window: "Error creating directory /media/username/harddiskname/testdir: Input/output error"). But actually, when I open file manager, that folder is created.

3. STRANGE BEHAVIOR:
   Sometimes, when I close file manager (Nautilus for example), unmount/mount that hard drive, I am actually ABLE to save file from Gedit and mkdir from terminal. Especially when I deinstall Nautilus, everything works fine (except I have no file manager :) ).
   But when I open nautilus and try to create "New folder", popup error message like above appears, and after that I am again not able to save in Gedit, mkdir in terminal, etc.
   NOTE: All the time I can read files from that drive as normal. I see all the files, can open and close them like normal.
4. ADDITIONAL DETAILS
   Strange behavior coincide with installation of Krusader file manager. Installation of Krusader actually works fine, and first use too, but after restarting the system (or after sleep mode, Im not sure) problem appears. Uninstallation of Krusader didn't help.
   There are a few more details which I can add, but don't want to make question cluttered. Of course, I searched for solution on internet, but nowhere I find this kind of behavior, and still have no solution. I just suspect that problem is file manager, not drive. Drive works just fine when accessed from windows.

Thanks for any suggestion.
P.S. My linux skills are on basic level, still I can sometimes deal with advanced things.

Comment: Due to IO errors; I'd stop trying to use the drive, but validate it's health using it's SMART (ie. drive's own diagnostics).  Just because windows works without issues means nothing (except windows is using another part of the disk), but if your drive is failing - windows could start having problems too; so if you've data on the drive that matters - stop using it, assess it's health & if necessary get any data off it that matters - ie. assess now.  (do it from 'live' media so drive is not being used; eg. Ubuntu install media running from thumb-drive)

Comment: @guiverc Thank you, I already suspected that disk has bad sectors or something like that, but turned to think that maybe it is not case because everything works fine when file manager is closed/uninstalled. But you motivate me to do something from that side. I'll explain in answer what I did, and seems solved a problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app `SMART Data`, and it may take 2 screenshots to show all of the scrollable data, and I'll take a look. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: If you stop using the area of the disk the problem may "*seem*" to go away, but the problem will remain (and could be a sign of troubles ahead when you save new files, or if it's a growing problem).  Thus my suggestion to assess the problem & make informed decision. I have drives that I continue to be able to use 2-3 years after bad areas were detected (with my locking of that area of disk so I won't go near it), but it could also be your warning of a dying disk (which usually starts as problems in one area). It's your data, your disk so you decide... You have a good backup strategy I take it\

Comment: @heynnema Thank you for your help. I explained that in meantime I repairs disk from windows, so I put screenshots in my answer below.

Comment: @guiverc Thank you. Could you explain a little more how to do it from "live" media: connect Ubuntu installation thumb-drive, and what after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, @guiverc made a comment which motivates me to look for disk bad blocks.
I already read about that possibility but turned away from it because everything works fine when file manager is closed/uninstalled.
This is what solved (at least it seems solved for now) my problem:

I already said that drive is used regularly from ubuntu and from windows. So I logged into windows and tried to delete junk folders and files I created in last two days trying to understand strange behavior. Dozens of folders was deleted as normal, but one folder resist to be deleted, and windows popup appears with error:
"Error 0x80070570 the file or directory is corrupted and unreadable" with suggestion to look for explanation of that error code.

I did it, and find this page: 
https://windowsreport.com/error-0x80070570-windows-10/
which, among other things, suggests to check hard drive for errors:
1. Open This PC, right click the partition you want to scan and choose Properties from the menu
2. Navigate to Tools tab and click the Check button.
3. Check Scan and repear.. 
It lasts for 10 minutes, and was successful.

Restarted and logged in Ubuntu.
With no file manager opened (Nautilus) tried to save file with Gedit successfuly, tried to mkdir from terminal successfuly (just to be sure everything works not worse than before), and finally open Nautilus, and successfully created folder. Save from Gedit, and mkdir from terminal which usually stoped working after opening Nautilus, now works fine (knock - knock :) )

So problem seems to be solved, but I will keep an eye on, and report if problem reappears.

UPDATE:
Screenshots from Disks app and SMART data, as suggested by @guiverc and required by @heynnema .
"Unfortunately" I can bring only screenshots after windows successfully repairs drive:

[image: Disks app after win repairs]

[image: SMART data after win repairs]

Comment: The disk SMART Data looks good. Why use exFAT if you want to share files between W10 and Ubuntu. NTFS would be a better choice.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for your opinion. Well, I've searched about how to dual boot with drive accessible from both systems and recommendations was that drive must be FAT for that purpose :/

Comment: If you search here on AU, I think that you'll find that the consensus  is to use NTFS, as both operating systems can read/write to it.